# Problems With My .pro File and External Libraries (With Example Guideline Makefile)

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I'm trying to create a quick GUI which will act as a frontend for some software written by someone else. The problem I'm having seems to be a library issue but I'm going around in circles with the error. Any suggestions on what the error means or what I can try would be greatly appreciated.

### File Structure

```
~/Ph2_DAQ
```

Inside this I have the many folders but the ones I refer to are:

```
lib/ src/ TestStand/
```

### The Problem

This is the .pro file I've made in `/TestStand` which needs to be compiled in C++11:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TestStand
TEMPLATE = app

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -pedantic -std=c++11 `root-config --cflags --evelibs` #Added these flags

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/cactus/include ../ 

#LIBS += -L/opt/xdaq/lib
#LIBS += -lcactus_extern_pugixml -lcactus_uhal_log -lcactus_uhal_grammars -lcactus_uhal_uhal

LibraryDirs = /opt/cactus/lib /opt/xdaq/lib ../lib #/***Added to the generated file from here...
LibraryPaths = $(LibraryDirs:%=-L%)
LIBS += $(LibraryPaths:%=-L%) -uhal -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread -lboost_regex -lcactus_extern_pugixml -lcactus_uhal_log -lcactus_uhal_grammars -lcactus_uhal_uhal `root-config --glibs` -lPh2_Interface -lPh2_Description -lPh2_System -lPh2_Tools #***/ ... To here

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

To test I can call in a special external library which I know I will need, I add this to my `main.cpp`:

```
#include "uhal/uhal.hpp"
```

I run `qmake` on this and I get a few warnings and errors once I run `make` in the directory that all look pretty similar:

```
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/bin/uic mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
g++ -c -pipe -pedantic -std=c++11 `root-config --cflags --evelibs` -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtCore -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include -I/opt/cactus/include -I.. -I. -I. -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from /opt/cactus/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:29:0,
                 from /opt/cactus/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/cactus/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:29,
                 from /opt/cactus/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/cactus/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from /opt/cactus/include/uhal/log/exception.hpp:50,
                 from /opt/cactus/include/uhal/ValMem.hpp:43,
                 from /opt/cactus/include/uhal/uhal.hpp:40,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/opt/cactus/include/boost/bind/arg.hpp: In constructor âboost::arg<I>::arg(const T&)â:
/opt/cactus/include/boost/bind/arg.hpp:37:22: warning: typedef âT_must_be_placeholderâ locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
         typedef char T_must_be_placeholder[ I == is_placeholder<T>::value? 1: -1 ];
```

It then sends a few erros that it can't find my custom libraries despite them being there:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/ld: cannot find -lPh2_Description #(and the same for -lPh2_System & lPh2_Tools)
```

and if I do the `ls` command:

```
ls ../lib/
libPh2_Description.so libPh2_System.so libPh2_Tools.so
```

### The Guideline

The software has this `Makefile` which has this structure, so I naturally tried copying parts since the software does compile on my computer:

```
CC              = gcc
CXX             = g++
CCFlags         = -g -O1 -w -Wall -pedantic -fPIC `root-config --cflags --evelibs`
#DevFlags                    = -D__CBCDAQ_DEV__
DevFlags                   =

IncludeDirs     =  /opt/cactus/include ../

IncludePaths            = $(IncludeDirs:%=-I%)

LibraryDirs = /opt/cactus/lib /opt/xdaq/lib ../lib
LibraryPaths = $(LibraryDirs:%=-L%)

ExternalObjects = $(LibraryPaths) -lpthread -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_regex -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lcactus_extern_pugixml -lcactus_uhal_log -lcactus_uhal_grammars -lcactus_uhal_uhal `root-config --glibs` -lPh2_Interface -lPh2_Description -lPh2_System -lPh2_Tools

%.o: %.cc %.h
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 $(DevFlags) $(CCFlags) $(UserCCFlags) $(CCDefines) $(IncludePaths) -c -o $@ $<


all: testpgrm datatest2cbc datatest8cbc mcp system calibrationtest

testpgrm: test.cc
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 $(CCFlags) -o $@ $< $(IncludePaths) $(ExternalObjects)
    mv $@ ../bin

datatest2cbc: readdatatest2CBC.cc
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 $(CCFlags) -o $@ $< $(IncludePaths) $(ExternalObjects)
    mv $@ ../bin

datatest8cbc: readdatatest8CBC.cc
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 $(CCFlags) -o $@ $< $(IncludePaths) $(ExternalObjects)
    mv $@ ../bin

system: systemtest.cc
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 $(CCFlags) -o $@ $< $(IncludePaths) $(ExternalObjects)
    mv $@ ../bin

mcp: mcp.cc
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 $(CCFlags) -o $@ $< $(IncludePaths) $(ExternalObjects)
    mv $@ ../bin

calibrationtest: calibrationtest.cc
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 $(CCFlags) -o $@ $< $(IncludePaths) $(ExternalObjects)
    mv $@ ../bin
```

### Output From Terminal

Before the warnings:

```
g++ -c -pipe -pedantic -std=c++11 root-config --cflags -evelibs -pthread -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtCore -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include -I/opt/cactus/include -I.. -I. -I. -o main.o main.cpp In file included from /opt/cactus/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:29:0,...
```

And After the warnings:

```
g++ -c -pipe -pedantic -std=c++11 `root-config --cflags --evelibs` -pthread -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtCore -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include -I/opt/cactus/include -I.. -I. -I. -o mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtCore -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include -I/opt/cactus/include -I.. -I. -I. mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -pedantic -std=c++11 `root-config --cflags --evelibs` -pthread -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtCore -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include/QtGui -I/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/include -I/opt/cactus/include -I.. -I. -I. -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib -o TestStand main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o    -L/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib -L/opt/xdaq/lib  -uhal -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_regex -lcactus_extern_pugixml -lcactus_uhal_log -lcactus_uhal_grammars -lcactus_uhal_uhal `root-config --glibs` -lPh2_Interface -lPh2_Description -lPh2_System -lPh2_Tools -lQtGui -L/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.5/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtCore -lpthread
```

### What Should Be on Output

This is the output from the software (not the GUI) when it compiles correctly using the above makefile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O1 -w -Wall -pedantic -fPIC `root-config --cflags -evelibs` -o calibrationtest calibrationtest.cc -I/opt/cactus/include -I../ -L/opt/cactus/lib -L/opt/xdaq/lib -L../lib -lptost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_regex -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lcactus_extern_pugixml -lcactus_uhal_log -lcactus_uhal_grammars -lcactus_uhal_uhal `root-config --glibs` -lPh2_interfaceDescription -lPh2_system -lPh2_Tools
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the current current directory of your make? Are you using shadow-build option, which generated a build-directory next to your application directory. When using relative library-paths these can getting wrong. So try to use absolute paths or adapt the

```
../lib
```

to a relative path, which matches to the lib directory.

And can you show the output in your console for the ld-step. I am not sure, feels like the library paths are not set correctly. Does it works when you write:

```
LIBS += -L/opt/xdaq/lib
LIBS += -lcactus_extern_pugixml -lcactus_uhal_log -lcactus_uhal_grammars -lcactus_uhal_uhal
```

instead?

Comment: The directory I make is in `/TestStand` so `../lib` should work.

Comment: Using the full path doesn't work either (so `/home/user/Ph2DAQ_dev/lib`).

And I don't think I am using shadow build

Comment: What I don't understand is why it's looking in the dev-tools folder for those libraries... when they're located in ~/Ph2DAQ_dev/lib

Comment: I have edited my question and included the outputs. Before the warnings is before it comes up with all the weird "warning" errors. Then comes the next library output followed by the:

`/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8/ld: cannot find -lPh2_Interface`

Comment: Have you ever tried to add this path: ~/Ph2DAQ_dev/lib ? Normally your output looks great. I would just check all the alsolute paths to see if there are the .so located. If everything is fine: I don't have a clue at the moment.

Comment: I have indeed. How strange. Maybe someone else can shed light on this weird problem...

Comment: It seems that your ../lib is not in the list of the library paths.

Comment: Have you run qmake after changing it in the pro-file?

Comment: `rm Makefile`
`qmake TestStand.pro`
`make`

Comment: OK there we go, the correct output from the making of a file in `/src` (so when in `/TestStand`, located at `../src`)

Comment: Separated the whole thing out and added the library names step by step and it works. I have a bunch of new error messages now but they're not to do with this =D